# How to stop duplicate strings in Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am iterating over a LinkedList, but cannot figure out how to only iterate over each unique string. I was thinking of using a ForEach loop to iterate over each unique string, but not sure if its possible or how to do it. Thanks!

```
@Override
public List<String> listRegressions() {
    // TODO Implement this, ideally in better than O(n^2)

    LinkedList<String> regressionUnikey = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < getListSize(); i++) {
        Integer bestGrade = getBestGrade(students.get(i).getUnikey());

        Integer recentGrade = getSubmissionFinal(students.get(i).getUnikey()).getGrade();
        if (recentGrade < bestGrade) {
            regressionUnikey.add(students.get(i).getUnikey());
        }
    }

    return regressionUnikey;
}
```

One testcase result

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[b, c, f]> but was:<[b, b, c, c, f, f]>
```

Comment: Why not use a Set? Do you actually need a list?

Comment: Convert List to Set and iterate over Set.

Comment: Any specific reason for using LinkedList ?

Comment: LinkedHashSet<String> regressionUnikey = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

Comment: There's not really a specific reason why, and i'm not familiar with LinkedHashSet.

Comment: @Nicholasmita Get familiar with many different types of structures. It's well worth the time. The use cases for plain LinkedLists are pretty limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you even use a `LinkedList` ? I do not see a reason to have the output ordered anyhow.

```
Set<String> regressionUnikey = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < getListSize(); i++) {
        String key = students.get(i).getUnikey();
        Integer bestGrade = getBestGrade(key);

        Integer recentGrade = getSubmissionFinal(key).getGrade();
        if (recentGrade < bestGrade) {
            regressionUnikey.add(key);
        }
    }
```

Use a `HashSet` simply. It would ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Or a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to preserve the items order.